# NVelocity syntax (#) breaks the syntax highlighting binded to vm extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax, highlighting, nvelocity

As far as I know, there's no way to get good NVelocity syntax highlighting for Visual Studio 2010 that preserves html, css and javascript highlighting as well, so the way I do it is to go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension and add vm to HTML Editor.

This works fine, I don't really need syntax highlighting for #if #else etc, but if the document begins with #, it will break the HTML Editor syntax.

```
 ## Some comment, or anything with #NVelocity syntax
 <div>this will not have syntax highlighting</div>
```

However, it WILL work if I put any  first, like this

```
 <!-- Unwanted comment -->
 ## Some comment, or anything with #NVelocity syntax
```

Anyone have any idea how to make it work with # in the beginning of the document?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the syntax highlighter... Consider sending the Castle team a patch :)